# Disable an item in the combobox: devexperss winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, devexpress

```
this.Solvers.AutoHeight = false;
this.Solvers.Buttons.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton[] {
new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Combo)});
this.Solvers.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
"Apple",
"Orange",
"Custom",
"Grapes"});
this.Solvers.Name = "Solvers";
this.Solvers.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor;
this.Solvers.EditValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ricbSolvers_EditValueChanged);
```

when i open the application,i will check for some value.if vaule is false the button "orange " should be disabled.How to achieve this.

```
if(value==false)
{
//diable button orange
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve? Prevent user from selecting orange? Why don't you just remove it?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič.Basic use is here we are checking for some licenses for apple ,orange and all.is it is unlicinsed then we should use the orange or apple item

Comment: basically we need to enable and disable the item in the combobox bases on some parameter

Answer (score 1):

ComboBox edit doesn't support this functionality. However I would try handling [DrawItem](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit.DrawItem) and [CloseUp](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.PopupBaseEdit.CloseUp) events.

Something like this:

```
private void Solvers_DrawItem(object sender, ListBoxDrawItemEventArgs e) 
{
  var s = e.Item.ToString();
  var enabled = IsEnabled(s);

  if (!enabled) {
    e.Apperance.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
  }
}

private void Solvers_CloseUp(object sender, CloseUpEventArgs e) 
{
  var s = e.Value.ToString();

  e.AcceptValue = IsEnabled(s);
}
```